# Making bold subsection-headings in math, but not bold in ToC

Tags: math-mode, table-of-contents, sectioning, bold

I am writing in the document type `article`, and I wish to have my subsection appear in bold itself, but appear normal in the ToC. I am trying to write a chemical formula, which automatically converts the text to non-bold, when using `\ce`. I chose to do it like this:

```
\subsection{formation of $\mathbf{N_2O}$ during $\mathbf{NH_3 - SCR}$}
```

This will make the subsection appear bold, but also it will make the text in `\mathbf` appear bold in the ToC. I would like to just have the sections appear bold, and the subsections to appear normal in the ToC

Comment: I don't see `\ce` here?

Comment: Thanks! it worked out just fine. I just had to replace \mathbf with \mathrm to make the chemical equations appear non-italic in the [...]

Comment: no I couldn't use it, since I couldn't make it appear in bold when using \ce. it was irrelevant information now I think about it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `\ce` is used, there's no need to use either `\mathbf` nor the optional argument of the `\subsection` command at all.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Foo}
\subsection{Foobar}
\subsection{formation of \ce{N2O} during \ce{NH3}-SCR}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `\mathbf` from the section head, and then just specify that you want math to be bold in the heading at the same point as you specify bold text, for example in `article` the default definition is

```
\newcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
```

and you want

```
\newcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\large\bfseries\boldmath}}
```