# Unbolded subsection on the ToC including math expression or equation but bolded subsection on subsection header

Tags: table-of-contents, bold

I have the exactly similar question with this [Making bold subsection-headings in math, but not bold in ToC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287615/making-bold-subsection-headings-in-math-but-not-bold-in-toc). But i can't use `\ce` since i need an actual use for mathbf that is integral and differential or a function with square root. I've tried that and it was fail to bold the subsection. So, i really need `\mathbf` or maybe there is another way to accomplish this? And as i suggest on the title, the subsection must be unbolded on the ToC including the math expression. Hope you can help me. Thanks.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,openany
%,draft
]{book}
%\usepackage{pgf, tikz}
\usepackage[a4paper, inner=4cm, outer=3cm, top=4cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\sloppy
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[column=O]{cellspace}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{notesep={:},round,aysep={, },citesep={;}}
\usepackage[depth=2]{bookmark}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multirow}
\hypersetup{hidelinks}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{cals} %====> multipage table
%\usepackage{maplestd2e}  %\
\usepackage{xcolor}      % ===> maple code
\usepackage{graphicx}    %/

\showboxbreadth=100
\showboxdepth=100

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%5   BAD BOXES   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\hfuzz=60pt
\hbadness=10000

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newlist{ColEnum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[ColEnum,1]{label = \arabic*), left = 0pt, nosep, 
    before= {\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}\RaggedRight},
        after = {\end{minipage}}}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\endgraf\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}p{#1}}

\newlist{tabitem}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tabitem]{label=\textbullet, noitemsep,leftmargin=*,topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt, nosep, before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}, after=\end{minipage}}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Res}{Res}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{5pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{4pt}
\setlength\bibhang{25pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Teorema}[section]
\newtheorem{cl}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{lm}{Lemma}[section]

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definisi}[section]
\newtheorem{exmp}{Contoh}
\renewcommand{\proofname}{\rm\bf{Bukti}}

\renewcommand\tablename{Tabel}
\renewcommand\figurename{Gambar}



\patchcmd{\section}{\bfseries}{\bfseries\boldmath}{}{}
%\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\contentsname}{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\contentsname}}{}{}
%\patchcmd{\listoffigures}{\listfigurename}{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}{\listfigurename}}{}{}
%\patchcmd{\listoftables}{\listtablename}{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase\listtablename}{\listtablename}}{}{}
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{10pt}
\setlength{\cftbeforesubsecskip}{10pt}

\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\linespread{1.5}
\pagestyle{plain}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{1}
\renewcommand\cftchapdotsep{\cftdotsep}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
    {\normalfont\bfseries\centering}
    {}{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\section}
    {\normalfont\bfseries}
    {\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
    {\normalfont\bfseries}
    {\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{DAFTAR ISI}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{DAFTAR TABEL}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{DAFTAR GAMBAR}
\newcommand\dd{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

%\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\null\protect\hfill{Halaman}\protect\par}
\setlength\parindent{1.25cm} 

\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill{Halaman}\par}
%\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\afterpage{~\hfill{Halaman}\par\medskip}}
\addtocontents{lot}{~\hfill{Halaman}\par}
\addtocontents{lof}{~\hfill{Halaman}\par}
\addtocontents{app}{~\hfill{Halaman}\par}

\makeatletter
\def\ttl@mkchap@i#1#2#3#4#5#6#7{%
    \ttl@assign\@tempskipa#3\relax\beforetitleunit
    \vspace{\@tempskipa}%<<<<<< REMOVE THE * AFTER \vspace
    \global\@afterindenttrue
    \ifcase#5 \global\@afterindentfalse\fi
    \ttl@assign\@tempskipb#4\relax\aftertitleunit
    \ttl@topmode{\@tempskipb}{%
        \ttl@select{#6}{#1}{#2}{#7}}%
    \ttl@finmarks  % Outside the box!
    \@ifundefined{ttlp@#6}{}{\ttlp@write{#6}}}
\makeatother

%DAFTAR LAMPIRAN (APPENDIX)
\newcommand{\listappendixname}{DAFTAR LAMPIRAN}
\newlistof{appendix}{app}{\listappendixname}
\setcounter{appdepth}{2}    
\renewcommand{\theappendix}{Lampiran\space\arabic{appendix}}
\renewcommand{\cftappendixpresnum}{}
\setlength{\cftbeforeappendixskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\cftappendixnumwidth}{.9in}
\newlistentry[appendix]{subappendix}{app}{1}
\renewcommand{\thesubappendix}{\theappendix.\arabic{subappendix}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubappendixpresnum}{Appendix\space}
\setlength{\cftsubappendixnumwidth}{1in}
\setlength{\cftsubappendixindent}{0em}
\renewcommand{\listofappendix}{\begingroup
\tocfile{\listappendixname}{app}
\endgroup}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{app}

\newcommand{\myappendix}[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{appendix}%
    \section*{\theappendix\space #1}%
    \addcontentsline{app}{appendix}{\protect\numberline{\theappendix}#1}%
    \par
}

\newcommand{\subappendix}[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{subappendix}%
    \subsection*{\thesubappendix\space #1}%
    \addcontentsline{app}{subappendix}{\protect\numberline{\thesubappendix}#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\frontmatter %

\pagestyle{fancy}   
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{DAFTAR PUSTAKA}


\begin{spacing}{0.1}
    \tableofcontents
    
\end{spacing}
\begin{spacing}{1.5}
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables
    \listofappendix
%   \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listappendixname}
\end{spacing}

\mainmatter 
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Proof of \ce{$\int f(s)$} is \ce{$0$}}

\backmatter
\bibliography{dafpus}
\bibliographystyle{unejstyle}
\nocite{*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How about `\subsection[Proof of $\int f(s)$ is $0$]{Proof of $\mathbf{\int f(s)}$ is $\mathbf{0}$}`?

Comment: Or, `\subsection[Proof of $\int f(s)=0$]{\boldmath Proof of $\int f(s)=0$}`.